# Cloudflare Worker - Download a File using Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, worker

I making a cloudflare worker that have to fetch a url pointing to a file. I want to redirect the request to download this file. The download happens, but with no extension and no name of the file. Can i read the response (return binary/octet-stream) and set the filename before download the file? Or some way to read the binary response and build a file with a name and download the file?

Im using fetch:

```
let file_response = await fetch(url)
.then((data) => {

}
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Look in response headers, maybe  filename is there

Comment: but how i transform the response in a file and redirect the request to download it?

Comment: Transform the response in a file? I don't understand... If download happens, headers should contain a filename too. After,  you can do .then(data => data.blob()).then([...]

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/blob)

Comment: I will try to explain: The download happens, but downloads a file without extension and only with "download" name. This is not the name of the file (the filename is "exams.zip"). This file is on a aws bucket, and i dont know why this happens. And worker have a limited javascript, so i have to make with fetch. I want a way to fetch the url, get the response and create a file with this binary response, setting the name and the extension before the download.

Comment: Ok, with  Blob you can. Read link I posted

Comment: or post your full code, if possible!

Comment: Pierpy thanks for the answer..The code is the one i posted..a simple fetch to a url.. But the response arrives not with the blob() , but with the text() function of the response. But when i redirect the request, downloads in that way i explained. I looked the url you posted, but uses URL.createObjectURL and in the cloudflare worker i cant use createObjectURL. Im trying to find another way to build the file.

Comment: :-) Ok. From Cloudflare you can serve some HTML;  `<a href=(link here..) download="exams.zip">Download</a>`   
The `download` attribute properly sets filename for downloads

Comment: You´re the man! Is not the perfect way, but i think i can return an html with a link to download...Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250029/discussion-between-pierpy-and-rafael-spessotto).

Comment: Sure, but i will post what i found, and worked for me:

Answer (score 4):

After a while, i found a way. Maybe can help others!

```
var requestOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      redirect: 'follow'
    };

    let file_response = await fetch(url,requestOptions)
    let data = await file_response.blob();
    contentDisposition = "attachment; filename=" + "file123.zip";
    return new Response(data, {
      status: 200,
      headers: { "content-type": "application/octet-stream", "Content-Disposition": contentDisposition}
    })
```

and now, the file is downloaded with the given name "file123.zip"